# Get an XML response with a Java HTTP POST request on GeoNetwork

Tags: java, geonetwork, jetty, http-post

I try to complete automatically my GeoNetwork catalog with a Java client. My metadata respect the ISO 19115 schema and the interactions are performed trough CSW.

To insert metadata, I send HTTP POST request. The content of my request respects the CSW XML request format.  No matter the library (io, apache commons, geotools), I always have the same HTML response as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  SYSTEM "html">
<html ng-app="gn_login" lang="eng" id="ng-app">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>My GeoNetwork catalogue - My organization</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="keywords" content="">
      <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 48x48" type="image/png" href="../../i$
      <link href="rss.search?sortBy=changeDate" rel="alternate" type="applicati$
      <link href="portal.opensearch" rel="search" type="application/opensearchd$
      <link href="/geonetwork/static/gn_login_default.css" rel="stylesheet" med$
      <link href="/geonetwork/static/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" $
      <link href="/geonetwork/static/ng-skos.css" rel="stylesheet" media="scree$
      <link href="/geonetwork/static/srv_custom_style.css" rel="stylesheet" med$
   </head>
   <body data-ng-controller="GnCatController">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default gn-top-bar" data-ng-hide="layout.hideTo$
      <div data-ng-include="'../../catalog/templates/signin.html'"></div>
      <div ng-include="'../../catalog/templates/info.html'"></div><script src="$
         <div class="alert" data-ng-hide=""><strong></strong>
         </div>
      </noscript>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have already try to perform GET and POST requests on a folder jetty server with success. My GET request works with my GeoNetwork. But as soon as as I perform POST request, the response is this html sheet.

I have tried two types of POST requests. 
Login POST request (".../geonetwork/srv/fre/xml.user.login"   OR   ".../geonetwork/srv/fre/catalog.signin") with this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin</password>
</request>
```

And insert POST request with an ISO 19115 metadata (".../geonetwork/srv/fre/csw-transaction"   OR   ".../geonetwork/srv/fre/metadata.insert") like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csw:Transaction service="CSW" version="2.0.2" xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2">
        <csw:Insert>
                <gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:wms="http://www.opengis.net/wms" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/199$
....
```

No matter the type of the post request, I always have the html sheet as response. I start my GeoNetwork with the start.jar of jetty. Do you know how to directly request the server to execute the POST requests and to get an XML response as expected?

Comment: What's your POST content?  Are you trying to interact through CSW? Can you give more details on your GeoNetwork instance

Comment: Please edit your question to add all these extra details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [my answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/232346/44978) to my own question can help you with the login request.

I use a `POST` request, sending login credentials in the `Authorization` header to the authorization endpoint `geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.signin`. This also works for other requests directly to geonetwork resources.

I have not used CSW transactional requests so far, but would suspect it to work the same way.

**EDIT:**
Another thing came to my mind and might explain the difference between `GET` and `POST`: Did you check, that your user has rights to use transaction on the respective datasets?

**EDIT:**

I did face the same issue again with my own implementation. Somehow, querying the `catalog.signin` endpoint didn't work for me now, when I want to reuse the response `JSESSIONID` to login to GeoNetwork.

What I had to do is to query `http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/j_spring_security_check` and exactly follow all `302` redirects with my HTTPClient including issued cookies (intermediate sessionid's). After I receive a fresh `JSESSIONID` from the last redirect, I can then use this one to query private GeoNetwork resources.

I use `java.net.HttpURLConnection`, which has a default follow redirect property, which I had to set to false: `con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);`
This is due to the fact, that this does not seem to include cookies by default when doing redirects, so it does not work in this case and I had to do the redirects manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to send my login credentials as admin directly to geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.signin. The response is a 302 error but I get a cookie associated to my httpClient; And after, when I try to send a transactional request with the same httpClient (which has the cookie), I have again a 302 error (the request does not insert what I want). How can I get XML CSW standard responses? How can I know if I have the rights to send transactionnal requests?

Comment: For the user rights: you can go to your GeoNetwork web interface -> admin console -> users and groups -> manage users. Your user should be at least Editor or Adminstrator, I guess. But since you say, you use an admin account for the post, I would expect it to work actually.

Comment: According to [here](http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/3.0.5/eng/users/administrator-guide/managing-users-and-groups/index.html#users-groups-and-roles), you should be able to do all metadata creation with the admin profile. Maybe check if you can create records manually in the web interface.

Comment: There is no problem to create or import metadata manually (when I am logged as admin with my browser). I have read your answer to your own question. How do you get the "Location", where do you find it?

Comment: I succeded to display the error response and the cookie. But with a 302 error, I do not know how to display the new URL.

Comment: From your response object you should get the `Location`-Header somehow like `response.getHeaders.get("Location");`

Comment: Which version of GeoNetwork are you using? I just went to execute a sample insert transaction via my GN 3.0.6 browser interface -> admin console -> settings -> CSW Test. This will send the request against `...geonetwork/srv/eng/csw-publication`. This is different from your `csw-transaction` which you stated in your question.

Comment: Tanks a lot. I succeed to login now !!! My login POST request gets a 200 response and a cookie. But when I try to send a transactional POST request, I have a 302 error and the Location is the login URL. So it seems that I am not logged but I use the httpClient and the cookie of my previous login request. An idea?

Comment: I use GeoNetwork 3.2.1 (current release). I have also tried ../csw-publication.

Comment: Have you tried sending the transaction request also with your credentials instead of the cookie (as a workaround)?

Comment: Not yet. What do you mean by transaction with credentials? Do I have to use the login/password in my request or in the URL?

Comment: I mean to make the transactino request the same way like you do the call to catalog.signin, using username and password instead of the cookie. If you currently send the login password in the body, I would try as I said in my answer above, putting the credentials into the Authorization header of your request.

Comment: See e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732422/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection) for the Authorization header.

Comment: So I tried to put the credentials directly in the request `postInsert.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "admin:admin");`. But I have still a 302 error with login location. I also tried to put the login/password in the XML body but it is weird because the body has to respect a CSW schema.

Comment: I do not understand. Because when I work with cookie session ID, the cookie used for the transactionnal request is the same as the one I got with the login request. Why do I have a 302 error with login location?

Comment: I forgot to precise that it does not work with the login password in the body. 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csw:Transaction service="CSW" version="2.0.2" xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2">
<username>admin</username>
<password>admin</password>
 <csw:Insert>
  <gmd:MD_Metadata...`

Comment: You should read on how to specify an Authorization header, as described in the link I posted in the last comment. Seems like you miss Base64 encoding. Specifying the password snippet AND your XML in the body won't work.

Comment: `String basicAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("admin:admin").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
   postInsert.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+basicAuth);`

Comment: I put the credentials in the header with the previous code. With this URL `http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw-publication`, I get a 400 error. And with this URL `http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/metadata.insert`, I get a 302 error with this location `/geonetwork/srv/eng/service-not-allowed?referer=/geonetwork/srv/eng/insert.metadata`. So, it seems that I am still not logged or the admin has not the rights.

Comment: I tried to verify exactly this, using the RESTClient AddOn in Firefox: `POST http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw-publication` with Basic Authentication (username/ password). With a read-only user, I get some html like you posted, with an admin user I get some XML ExceptionReport back from the CSW which means, that I was logged on successfully, according to me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60457/discussion-on-answer-by-tareq-get-an-xml-response-with-a-java-http-post-request).