# Authentication to GeoNetwork by third party application

Tags: api, geonetwork, authentication, url, angular

I linked the users table of GeoNetwork 3.10.2 with my application database so everytime I create/update a user in the app is also created/updated in geonetwork, now I want that once I log in the app, I also automatically be logged into GeoNetwork.
I found this thread about using JSESSION : [Accessing geonetwork API by JSESSIONID cookie](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231775/accessing-geonetwork-api-by-jsessionid-cookie)
but I got no success response

```
const httpHeaders = { headers: new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    }
    
let body = {"username": "userLogin","password": "userPass" };
this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.signin', body , httpHeaders)
      .pipe(map(( res: Response ) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)) )).subscribe( response => {
      console.log('response   :   ' ,response);      
});
```

from the file log I got :

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [31/Dec/2020:03:43:34 -0800] "POST /geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.signin HTTP/1.1" 403 1114
```

```
2020-12-31 04:29:19,569 ERROR [jeeves.xlinkprocessor] - Failed on #ANZLIC_Contact
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: #ANZLIC_Contact
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at jeeves.xlink.Processor.resolveXLink(Processor.java:202)
    at jeeves.xlink.Processor.doXLink(Processor.java:445)
    at jeeves.xlink.Processor.searchXLink(Processor.java:331)
    at jeeves.xlink.Processor.detachXLink(Processor.java:140)
    at org.fao.geonet.kernel.datamanager.base.BaseMetadataManager.getMetadata(BaseMetadataManager.java:702)
    at org.fao.geonet.kernel.datamanager.base.BaseMetadataManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3a6cdaae.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:651)
    at org.fao.geonet.kernel.datamanager.draft.DraftMetadataManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6009215e.getMetadata(<generated>)
    at org.fao.geonet.kernel.DataManager.getMetadata(DataManager.java:396)
    at org.fao.geonet.api.records.MetadataUtils.getRelated(MetadataUtils.java:109)
    at org.fao.geonet.api.related.Related.getRelated(Related.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesDispatcherServlet.access$101(JeevesDispatcherServlet.java:44)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesDispatcherServlet$1.doInTransaction(JeevesDispatcherServlet.java:56)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesDispatcherServlet$1.doInTransaction(JeevesDispatcherServlet.java:52)
    at jeeves.transaction.TransactionManager.runInTransaction(TransactionManager.java:73)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(JeevesDispatcherServlet.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.fao.geonet.web.CORSResponseFilter.doFilter(CORSResponseFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.fao.geonet.monitor.webapp.WebappMetricsFilter.doFilter(WebappMetricsFilter.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.fao.geonet.monitor.webapp.MetricsRegistryInitializerFilter.doFilter(MetricsRegistryInitializerFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geonetwork.http.SessionTimeoutCookieFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutCookieFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.PassthroughFilter.doFilter(PassthroughFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(JeevesDelegatingFilterProxy.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:760)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1480)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

[image]

Comment: what response did you get?

Comment: @IanTurton net:ERR_FAILED

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to update your question - we probably need to see the exact request you are sending, the response and the relevant section of the log file (with debugging turned up high).

Comment: @IanTurton I edited the question, as you can see from the log I got 403 error

Comment: @AN10 have you tried calling 
'http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/j_spring_security_check' instead with
let body = "username="+userLogin+"&password="+userPass; ?

Comment: @ulrich same error

Comment: @AN10 The error you posted above? Maybe you have some invalid datasets that you can check in your geonetwork app or in the database and correct them? Sounds like you have a field #ANZLIC_Contact which contains an invalid url. Maybe compare [this document](https://sourceforge.net/p/geonetwork/mailman/geonetwork-commit/?style=flat&viewmonth=201205&viewday=1).

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit tricky, to send a successful request to GeoNetwork, you need to include `X-XSRF-TOKEN` in the request header along with username and password defined by basic auth.
For getting the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` you need to send a `POST` request to the API `/{portal}/api/0.1/me` and save the token from the response. I'll demonstrate in the following example from [GeoNetwork API](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/3.10.x/en/api/the-geonetwork-api.html):

- Create a bash script file `script.sh` and paste the following:

```bsh
# GeoNetwork Credentials
export CATALOG=http://localhost:8080/geonetwork
export CATALOGUSER=user
export CATALOGPASS=pass

# Remove cookie if exists
rm -f /tmp/cookie;

# Get Cookie and extract XSRF-TOKEN
curl -s -c /tmp/cookie -o /dev/null -X POST "$CATALOG/srv/eng/info?type=me";

# Save the token
export TOKEN=`grep XSRF-TOKEN /tmp/cookie | cut -f 7`;

# Make a request to check the authentication (Should return "true")
curl -X POST -H "X-XSRF-TOKEN: $TOKEN" --user $CATALOGUSER:$CATALOGPASS -b /tmp/cookie \
  "$CATALOG/srv/eng/info?type=me"
```

- When executing the script `bash script.sh` you should get (authenticated). However, to implement this in your JavaScript application or whatever client you are using, you will need a Cookie Manager or something similar to handle token getting and saving.
- See `/{portal}/geonetwork/doc/api` for API documentation.